# Locking the position of a 2D sprite in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to lock the position (both x and y) of a sprite in Unity2D. I know that Rigidbody3D has constrain features, but Unity2D only has a "Fixed Angle" option (I'm making gears that mesh together and turn other gears so obviously I still want them to be able to turn). Is there anyway to fix a sprite into place?

Thanks

Comment: you could use a const float for the position? `int x = 4, y = 5; gameobject.transform.position = Vector2(x, y);`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? You have a gear in (x,y) position with a RigidBody component. Why do you need the rigidbody? What kind of interaction the gear is doing, are you doing it with physics simulation, it sound like it would be easier to do it using animations or sync rotations! Do have an specific reason for simulate the interaction with Physics?

Answer (score 0):

```
rigidBody2D.isKinematic=true;
```

To quote from the unity manual:

> The Is Kinematic setting switches off the physical behaviour of the
>   Rigidbody 2D so that it will not react to gravity and collisions. This
>   is typically used to keep an object under non-physical script control
>   most of the time but then switch to physics in a particular situation.

Therefore gravity doesnt affect it, collisions don't affect it. You can still move it using scripts, but it won't move via the physics engine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want the 'position-locked' game object to be kinematic. Kinematic rigid bodies cannot be moved by forces.

I'm not sure if this is an option in previous versions of Unity, but Rigidbody2D components come with the 'Is Kinematic' flag without any editor customization. So this can be done without creating scripts.

In Unity 5:
[image: Rigidbody2D Is Kinematic Flag]

Unity Rigidbody2D Doc:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html